# Pandas Normalization using groupby

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a two series column
First Column date which ranges from 2015-01-01 to 2019-01-01 and second column has some random values and I want to create a new column which should look like below

I have a pandas column like below

```
A1             B1

2015-01-01     A
2015-02-01     A
2015-03-01     A
2015-04-01     A
2015-01-01     B
2015-02-01.    B
-----
```

and I want a new column like below

```
A1              B1    B

2015-01-01       A   0
2015-02-01       A   1
2015-03-01       A   2
2015-05-01.      A   3
2015-01-01       B   0
2015-02-01.      B   1
```

I think I am supposed to use groupby function on B1 but not sure how to do that

Comment: Why 1-2-4? Shouldn't it be 1-2-3?  Also why did one of your months change in the output?

Answer (score 2):

#### [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df.assign(B=df.groupby('B1').cumcount())

            A1 B1  B
0   2015-01-01  A  0
1   2015-02-01  A  1
2   2015-03-01  A  2
3   2015-04-01  A  3
4   2015-01-01  B  0
5   2015-02-01  B  1
```

In place

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('B1').cumcount()
```